# In OSPF does a DR consume more resources than a BDR?

Tags: cisco, router, ospf

What is the best practice in conserving router resources? Should a single ABR router be the DR for all areas? Will that have a negative impact on the resources, or would it be better to let other routers act as the BR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In OSPF does a DR consume more resources than a BDR?

Both the DR and BDR for a link will form a full adjacency with any other OSPF routers on the same link. That is what consumes the most router resources.

> Should a single ABR router be the DR for all areas?

There is a problem with that idea. DR/BDR is per (broadcast/non-broadcast) link, not area. Each area may require multiple DRs/BDRs because there are multiple broadcast links in an area. You may also have entire areas that consist of point-to-point links, where there are no DRs in the entire area.

Assume a network as in this diagram, where all the links are ethernet (broadcast) links:

[image]

The ABR can certainly be the DR for all the **orange** links (it needs to have enough resources to handle being the DR for all those links), but each of the **red** links will also need a DR, and the ABR *cannot* be the DR for those links.

In fact, there is no single router in an area that can be the DR for all the **red** links in the area because no single router in any area is connected to all the **red** links in the area.

Also, for example, if all the links in the **yellow** area are point-to-point links, including the links to the ABR, then the **yellow** area will not have *any* DRs, and the ABR will not be a DR for the **yellow** area.

If *all* the links in the AS are point-to-point links, then there will be *no* DRs in the entire AS.

---

In an OSPF AS that has multiple areas, you must have at least one ABR, but DRs have nothing to do with an area. DRs are used on broadcast/non-broadcast links so that not every router on the link needs to form a full adjacency with every other router on the link, only with the DR and BDR for that link.

I think you are conflating two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Designated router (DR) selection: In general, the DR and backup designated router (BDR) on a multiaccess link (for example, Ethernet) have the most OSPF work to do. It is a good idea to select routers that are not already heavily loaded with CPU-intensive activities to be the DR and BDR. In addition, it is generally not a good idea to select the same router to be the DR on many multiaccess links simultaneously.

http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1763921&seqNum=6